# Virtual standard printer without dialog

Tags: java, printing, dialog

I would like to write a program that uses the default printer from the system (in this case a virtual PDF printer). The program should print one file (= inputFilePath).  After printing a new PDF file shall be created (= outputFilePath).

With all attempts I always get a dialog, which I don't want. Or printing with the virtual printer does not work.

So far I have experimented a lot with the class "PrintJob", but have not been able to get anything usable. Currently the code below gives the best result (unfortunately also with dialog).

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String inputFilePath = "C://TEST//test.msg";
        String outputFilePath ="C://TEST//test.pdf";
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();

        desktop.print(new File(inputFilePath));
     
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

best regards

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, since I have a printer called "PDF". It would seem that I cannot choose its output file name, but that might not be the case for you, but it *does* save the file, and *without* showing a dialog:

```
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.DocFlavor;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.Doc;
import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSizeName;
import javax.print.attribute.Attribute;

public class PdfPrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final String PDF_SERVICE = "PDF";
        PrintService[] services = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
        PrintService pdfService = Arrays.stream(services).filter(s -> PDF_SERVICE.equals(s.getName())).findFirst()
                .orElseThrow();
        /*
         If you want some info
        System.out.println(pdfService.getAttributes());
        Attribute[] attrs = pdfService.getAttributes().toArray();
        Arrays.stream(attrs).
            forEach(a ->System.out.printf("%s=%s%n", a.getName(), a));
        */
        try (InputStream fis = Files.newInputStream(Path.of(args[0]))) {
            DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF;
            DocPrintJob job = pdfService.createPrintJob();
            PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            aset.add(new Copies(1));
            aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
            Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, flavor, null);
            job.print(doc, aset);
        }

    }
}
```